# Windows Phone 8 Debugging-Error using MVVM-Light portable in Express-Editions

Tags: mvvm-light, visual-studio-express, portable-class-library

this is my first post her on stackoverflow. My english isn't so good, so i hope you understand my issue.

I'm using the Express-Editions of Visual Studio 2013 (Desktop, Web, Windows-Apps) and the Express Edition of Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Phone.
I created a Solution in Web-Developer 2013, created a class library and changed the project-file like mentioned in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8146504/2912109

So now i have a portable class library in my solution. I followed the instructions in this tutorial:
http://blog.tattoocoder.com/2013/01/portable-mvvm-light-move-your-view.html

So in the solution there is a portable class library containing "MainViewModel" and "ViewModelLocator" class. After that i opened the vs 2012 express for windows phone and opened the solutions, add a wp8 project and did the steps mentioned in the tutorial.
In the designer i can see the "Hello"-Message on the MainPage.xaml. But when i try to debugg the wp8 project, i get an error that's saying something like this:

"There is no network connection to 169.254.70.217:8016 anymore. Debugging was canceld".

Anybody an idea what i could try to get this running? Or isn't it possible to run this with the different express editions of visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found the solution. :-)
The problem was, that in the Windows Phone project there was a wrong version of Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll. The MVVM-Light Package by default installed there the v2.0 version of the dll. In the MVVM Light PCL project by defaukt it was the v4.0 version. So i changed the reference in WP8-project to the v4.0 and now it's debugging.

So if someone else runs in the same problem as me, here is the solution.

Greetings,
Daniel.